# Jumping segments in binary

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

My question is, is there a way in C# with a starting bit location to find the next binary digit within a byte that has a specified value of 0 or 1 without iteration (looking for the highest **performance** option).

As an example, if you had 10011 and started at the first bit (far right) and searched for the first 0, it would be the 3rd place going right to left. If you then started at the 3rd place and wanted to find the next 1, it would be at the 5th place (far left).

Thanks for any help and feel free to let me know if I need to provide anything further.

Edit: Here is my current code.

```
private int GetBinarySegment(uint uiValue, int iStart, int iMaxBits, byte bValue)
{
    int r = 0; uiValue >>= iStart; 
    if (uiValue == 0) return iMaxBits - iStart;
    while ((uiValue & 1) == bValue) { uiValue >>= 1; r++; }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: @STLDeveloper Only various forms of iteration. I started out with just shifting until the far right bit changed and would record the # of shifts until bit location 0 changed. If I needed to specify a 'starting' location, I would shift that amount before running the loop. Being that it is all binary, I was hoping for a much more elegant alternative.

Comment: What are you doing with the result? Something that has any chance of being done directly with a mask indicating that bit or does it really have to be an index?

Comment: @harold I guess to get information I should be more willing to give it. I was investigating a method of doing a multi-dimensional flood fill to identify all solid objects in a scalar field / voxel terrain environment for a game. I believe with a few similar tricks, I could get much better results performance wise than a typical iteration method flood fill.

Comment: I'll be storing my 3D terrain data in pages/chunks with a byte value per Y coordinate (X/Z being horizontal). If I can traverse the byte values in a "run-length encoding" sort of way, it just sounds like a neat approach from my perspective.

Comment: Ok well for one thing, you can skip the "start position"-shift by using the mask to set/unset the bit you found. Also, using wider words is almost always better for bitwise tricks since it reduces overhead. I'm not really sure yet what you're doing though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways, but they're ugly because there's no `_BitScanForward` or equivalent intrinsic. Still, you can actually compute this thing efficiently without needing a huge table.

First step: make a number that has a 1 at the position you're searching for and 0 everywhere else.

If searching for a 1, that means `x & -x`. If searching for a 0, use `~x & (x + 1)`.

Then, use one of the many ways to emulate either bitscan (there is only one set bit now, so it doesn't matter which side you search from). Some ways to do that are detailed [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogIEEE64Float) (not in C#, but you can convert them).

Comment: I have to ask, for performance reasons, would accessing a 2D Jagged Array not be faster than the options you present (considering I'd still need a log function or lookup table more than likely)? Not as elegant for sure, but performance is indeed my primary intent.

Comment: Probably not, that means dereferencing two dependent pointers (not too bad if they're in L1, but bad otherwise), whereas you can calculate the log with a cast to double and reinterpreting the bits. If you're going to use a table, make it a 1D-array and some math to get the index (and use `unsafe` access). If it makes sense to have a larger word size, that should be combined only with the mask/bitscan option, the tables would get too big (they might fit in memory, but a last-level cache miss takes in the order of a hundred cycles)

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup table.  That is, precalculate a 2D array indexed by byte value and current position.  You can do a separate table for zeros and ones, or you can combine it.

So for your example, you start at bit 0 of the number 19.  That happens to be a 1.  So if you lookup `nextBit[19][0]` it should return `1`, and so on.  Here's what a combined lookup table might look like.  It shows the next bit for both 0s and 1s:

```
nextBit[19][0] = 1   // 1
nextBit[19][1] = 4   // 1
nextBit[19][2] = 3   // 0
nextBit[19][3] = 4   // 0
nextBit[19][4] = 0   // 1
nextBit[19][5] = 6   // 0
nextBit[19][6] = 7   // 0
```

Obviously there is no 'next' for bit 7, and if 'next' returns 0, there are no more of that particular bit.

I may have interpreted your question incorrectly, but this technique can be modified to suit your purposes.  I initially thought you wanted to navigate through all 1-bits or 0-bits.  If instead you want to skip over consecutive 1-bits, then you just arrange your table in that way.  Or indeed, you can have a 'next' for both 0 and 1 at each position.